# C# - Genereic List copy one row add Another row

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am having a list of students and on condition i need to copy one row and add that row with minor change

for example:

Class Student having follwing  properties

```
public class Student
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
}
```

So while looping through List if marks = 90 i need to copy that row and add another row by updating section

```
 foreach (var item in studentData)
 {
    if(item.Section == 90)
    {
        //I need add some logic and update section and copy this item fully 
        //Add this modified item as new item to studentData
    }
 }
```

If student class had 3 items initially

```
1 "Sam" "A" 48
1 "John" "B" 68
1 "Broad" "A" 90
```

my expected output would be

```
1 "Sam" "A" 48
1 "John" "B" 68
1 "Broad" "A" 90
1 "Broad" "C" 90


//Where i added one more row modifying the section
```

What will be the easiest way to do this without much looping ? am stuck!!

I believe am clear with the question atleast with example !!

Thanks

Comment: what you mean copy? if the logic is true? you want `item` to be added to `studentData` after updating value of `item.section`? you cannot modify the collection overwhich you are iterating in a foreach loop

Comment: @DGibbs yes am updating...but am not sure like how to add the item again as a new Row. updated my question with some example

Comment: Do you really need to "copy and add"? So for example, you have one `Student` with `Id == 1` in your list, you want to end up with *two* `Student`s  with `Id == 1`? And what exactly are you testing? You say you want to test if "marks = 90", but your code suggests you're testing for `Section == 90`.

Comment: @ManishMishra i updated with some expected output data. Yes i know cannot modify the iterating  collection. What is the way to achieve the output ?

Comment: have a new collection, add the modified items to it, later, outside after the loop, merge the two

Comment: @Corak updated question with expected data !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't add items to the collections you're iterating, so just create another list, add your copies to it and in the end add items from that list to your `studentData`.

Something like this:

```
var copies = new List<Student>();

foreach (var item in studentData)
{
    if(item.Section == 90)
    {
        var copy = new Student();
        copy.ID = item.ID;
        copy.Name = item.Name;
        copy.Marks = item.Marks;
        copy.Section = // your updates to section
        copies.Add(copy);
    }
}

studentData.AddRange(copies);
```

Comment: Or you could iterate a copy of the original list e.g. `foreach(var item in studentData.ToList())` and add to the original inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to duplicate `Student`s (as I am not sure if this is good design), you can use following LINQ query:

```
list = list.AddRange(list.Where(x => x.Section  == 90)
                         .Select(x => new Student() 
                                      { 
                                         // here set fields as you wish
                                      }));
```

where in constructor you can create new user accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change your data structure. **Think objects, not table rows.**

For example:

```
public class Student
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{      
    // Something
}
```

Comment: To paraphrase the Batman movies: This is not the answer OP asked for, but probably the one OP needs. - Especially: "Think objects and not table rows."

Comment: @Corak I do what I can to save this dark city from horrible coding practices :P

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i< studentData.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = studentData[i];
            if (item.Marks == "90")
            {                    
                studentData.Insert(i, new Student { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name + "(smart one)", Section = item.Section, Marks = item.Marks});                    
                i++;
            }
        }
```